Is there a log of iPhone activity like screen wake
I’m trying to see when iPhone screen wake like the log or when the phone was used
The battery in settings has a log of Lock Screen when it was used but where is the time stamps
Or if there is any other way to know timestamps

The Battery section in Settings only shows when the phone transitioned to Lock Screen mode, which isn't as granular as what you're looking for.
However, there are a couple of workarounds you can consider:
App Usage in Screen Time:

Go to Settings > Screen Time

This feature provides insights into how much time you spend on your iPhone and individual apps. While it doesn't show timestamps for every wake event, it can indicate periods when your phone was likely in use based on app activity.
Notifications Log:
If you're looking to see when you interacted with your phone in relation to notifications, some third-party notification history apps might be helpful. Keep in mind that installing such apps requires permission access and might have privacy implications, so be sure to choose a reputable app with good reviews.
Charging Cycles:
This isn't a direct indicator of phone usage, but iPhones track charging cycles. Since most users charge their phones when the battery runs low, this might indirectly suggest periods of higher phone usage. You can find this information under

Settings > Battery > Battery Health


Like i can download logs off imazing but is there any for raise to wake, or screen wake that I can search for because the iPhones has logs of this
